# Tractability of a cardinality problem

Tags: convex-optimization

I have this confusion related to the convexity and tractability of a problem.

The given problem is

maximize $u^TSu$ subject to $||u||_2 = 1$  and card(u) <= r

This is a NP hard problem because of the combinatorial nature of the cardinality.

Then they say they relax it to a convex form like

maximize Tr(SU)

subject to Tr(U) =1 , Rank(U) = 1, $Card(U) <= r^2$ and U>=0

I didn't get the tractability of the second problem there is still $Card(U) <= r^2$. So how is it tractable?

Comment: What is the cardinality of a vector?

Comment: @dfeuer. Number of non zero elements